# Direct Proof of Parity of Roots

Tags: proof-verification, parity

So in my CS class regarding proofs, the professor wrote something interesting. His idea was:
If $n^2$ is odd then $n$ is odd.
However, his reason for this being true is that $\sqrt{2n+1}$ is also odd, but provided that as an axiom and provided no proof.
I understand how to proof this using the contrapositive, however is there a direct proof of (if $n^2$ is odd then $n$ is odd)?

Comment: if you are familiar with the representation of positive integers as product of primes, then using the prime property one can give a direct proof. However any such proof would have already involved bunch of statements where contrapositive method would have already been used. Of course one can go with contradiction method as well.

Comment: Two even numbers multiplied is even, and an even and odd number multiplied is even. The only way that two numbers multiplied together can create an odd number is if they are both odd.

Answer (score 4):

Since $n^2-n=n(n-1)$ is always even (one of $n$ or $n-1$ must be even) and $n^2$ is odd, $n$ is odd.

($n^2-(n^2-n)=n$, and odd-even=odd)

Comment: How does the last conclusion follow without using the claim?

Comment: @MichaelBurr $n^2-(n^2-n)=n$, and odd-even=odd.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that I give my students that the direct proof that if $n^2$ is odd is then $n$ is odd is much more challenging than the proof of the contrapositive is the following:

The square root function is hard to get a handle on.  The most direct proof would be to say that since $n^2$ is odd, $n^2=2k+1$ for some integer $k$ and then look at $\sqrt{2k+1}$.  The problem with this method is that it ends up trying to prove:

If $a$ is odd, then $\sqrt{a}$ is odd, which is not true (because $\sqrt{a}$ might be an integer).  So, the main challenge is that it's hard to work the assumption that $n^2$ is a square of an integer into the assumptions.

There are direct proofs, see @Akababa's answer +1, but they don't use the "expected" direct approach ("expected" in terms of basic proof courses).

Answer (score 0):

If $n^2$  is odd then:

$n^2 - 1 = (n - 1)(n + 1)$ is even.

RHS : (n +1) = (n - 1) + 2

1) If (n - 1) is odd then (n + 1) is odd

2) If (n -1) is even then (n + 1) is even.

So in our equation

$n^2 -  1 = (n - 1)(n + 1)$ both factors on the RHS are

1) both odd, or

2) both even.

Since the product $ n^2 - 1$ is even, only  option 2) remains.

If $n-1$, $n+1$ are even then $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Write $n=2m+r$ with $r=0$ or $r=1$.

Then $n^2=4m^2+4m+r^2$ and $n^2$ is odd iff $r=1$.

But then $n$ is odd.